# SQL table with a choice list (in pure SQL or with Java)

Tags: sql

I am willing to create myself a table in a database I make.
I don't know how to create a choice list to fill fields.

I explain my problem more specifically.
I want to obtain something like this

......................................................
table Employees (just example)
.......................................................
index / Name / Profession

1    /    John    /   Manager          ..........<=  here is the choice list between all possible jobs we have

How can I do this?
I want that my Employee table is editable (like in a GUI interface in Java), and that the values of profession can be edited (meaning, we can select a different value from the choice list).

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to have 2 tables in DB. one for employee and one for jobs.. 
In UI (java) to have the business to populate the drop down from jobs table.. when you save the UI info you have to write in both tables if is necessary.

e.g. Employee table: Id, name, job_id and Job table with Id, name. we need 2 methods one to read from employee and one to read from jobs. Dropdown have 3 properties: Id (id from job table, display - name from job table and binding value - job_id from employee table)
the drop down should have the options to add new values..
when you save in the db if you have new values in the job you have to add those values in the db and link to the employees

Comment: Thanks Marius, I will implement it like you said.